# Android: How to put a video in fullscreen mode while playing back

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer, android-fullscreen

I'm developing a custom video player with fullscreen option, where must be possible to switch between normal and fullscreen mode.

My initial ideia was to use a MediaPlayer with two SurfaceView, a normal SurfaceView and a fullscreen SurfaceView. The video would start playing in the normal SurfaceView and the fullscreen SurfaceView would be hidden. When the user click on the fullscreen button I would set the MediaPlayer to display on fullscreen SurfaceView and show it.

But, this doesn't work. I can't change the SurfaceHolder of the MediaPlayer while is playing back...

So, is there any way to do this?